# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: http, post, flutter, nested, uri

I'm creating a post request using package http.
My code is

```
final params = {
        'cartItem': {
          'sku': product.sku,
          'qty': '1',
          'quote_id': "xxxxx",
          'price': product.price.toString()
        }
      };
      final body = jsonEncode(params);
      var uri = Uri.parse(ClientConfigs.loadBasicURL()+APIPath.guestCartsPath+quoteID+"/items");
      uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: params);
      final response = await http.post(uri, headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ClientConfigs.accessToken}, body: body);
```

It broke with an exception that
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`
and it pointed to this code inside uri.dart class:

```
queryParameters.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == null || value is String) {
        writeParameter(key, value);
      } else {
        Iterable values = value; // Here is the broken point
        for (String value in values) {
          writeParameter(key, value);
        }
      }
    });
```

How to make a post request with nested body like mine?

Comment: Can you add, what is the ultimate URL that you are trying to invoke/acheive using those query params?

Comment: Then why do you need `uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: params);`? Anyway you are sending them in body as you desire?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because of this line:

```
uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: params);
```

The purpose of that is to replace the uri parameters for new ones, here is an example:

```
var uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/?q=test");
final replaceParams = {"q":"othertest"};
uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: replaceParams);
print(uri);
```

The output would be:

```
I/flutter ( 6060): http://www.example.com/?q=othertest
```

So, these are parameters for `GET` requests.

---

In your case you are confusing the `uri.replace()` for `GET` parameters and passing the `POST` parameters there. So, it seems that you don't need to call the `uri.replace()` method and that would solve this error.

Comment: Thank you! It solved when I immediately detect this by the comment of @Chenna Reddy.

Comment: Great, I answered to explain the problem and how you could use `uri.replace()` in case someone tried to use it and faced the same problem